# Auto refresh until iframe of certain height pops up

Tags: javascript, iframe, refresh

I am very new to JS and have only written a few scripts. I would like to write a script that auto refreshes a page until a page loads with an iframe that is under a certain height, say 1500 or so. Is this type of script possible?

Can it be modified from this code?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var LookFor = "random text"; // Enter text

if($('*:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length > 0) 
{
    alert("Found: " + LookFor);
}
else
{
    setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 10000);
}
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just target the iframe with jQuery and force it's height?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know what that means exactly. What would the outcome be if I were to do that?

Comment: I just looked up what you were talking about, but it's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I am looking for specific information that tends to load in iframes that are of a certain height, The iframe isn't in the same domain, so I can't use the code I posted to access it. I would like to do something similar to that, but have the page stop auto refreshing when an iframe of a certain height is found.

Comment: I may have found another approach to my problem. I used ctrl+f to search for specific text and the text was highlighted in the iframe. Is it possible to write a script that will auto ctrl+f with predesignated text and alert if found and auto refresh if not?